# Toggle - obter resultado true ou false

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Segue o código:

**Model:**

```
public bool teste{ get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
<div class="checkbox">
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.teste)
</div>
```

**Resultado HTML:**

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <div class="lcs_wrap"><input checked="checked" data-val="true" id="teste" name="teste" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <div class="lcs_switch lcs_checkbox_switch lcs_on">
        <div class="lcs_cursor"></div>
        <div class="lcs_label lcs_label_on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
        <div class="lcs_label lcs_label_off"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="teste" type="hidden" value="false">
</div>
```

**Script:**

Já tentei várias formas:

**Tentativa 1**

```
var teste= $('#teste').prop('checked');
```

**Tentativa 2**

```
var teste= $("#teste").is(":checked");
```

**Tentativa 3**

```
$('body').delegate('#teste', function() {
  var teste = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
});
```

Na linha : `<div class="lcs_switch lcs_checkbox_switch lcs_on">` = **true**

Quando for false `<div class="lcs_switch lcs_checkbox_switch lcs_off">` = **false**

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Eu acho que o problema está em o input #teste ser `type="hidden"`, não há propriedade `checked` para este tipo de input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
$('#teste[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $(this).next('div').toggleClass('lcs_on', this.checked).toggleClass('lcs_off', !this.checked);
});
```

```css
.lcs_on:after {
   content: 'lcs_on'; 
 }

.lcs_off:after {
   content: 'lcs_off'; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input data-val="true"  id="teste" name="teste" type="hidden" value="True">
    <div class="lcs_wrap">
        <input checked="checked" id="teste" name="teste" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <div class="lcs_switch lcs_checkbox_switch lcs_on">
            <div class="lcs_cursor"></div>
            <div class="lcs_label lcs_label_on">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="lcs_label lcs_label_off">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <input name="teste" type="hidden" value="false">
</div>
```

Você tinha um outro campo com o mesmo id antes do seu checkbox, por isso coloquei o [type="checkbox"] no seletor para diferenciar, basicamente isso observa a modificação no checkbox e faz o gerenciamento das classes como você explicou na pergunta, coloquei um css só pra ver melhor!

Answer (score 1):

1. Há dois inputs com o ID `teste`, o que não é aconselhável a fazer.
2. Conforme o @Miguel falou, o primeiro input é do tipo `hidden`, ou seja, não há propriedade `checked` para esse tipo de input.
3. Pelo que percebi você está utilizando o Razor do Asp.Net, o que pode estar acontecendo também, é que seu código javascript esteja executando antes mesmo de existir o elemento HTML na página, mas pra ter certeza, tem que debugar no Console do navegador e verificar se o elemento está lá, ex: `console.log($("#teste"));`.
4. Ao invés de tentar pegar o valor pela propriedade `checked`, tente pegar o valor pela propriedade `value`.

Comment: Sim, por causa `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.teste)` faz ele criar id. Vou remover ele e editar post